# How is modus pomens used in this proof sequence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here is my problem:

[image]

Why does this work specifically for step 7, p and p implies r. I can understand how to show r implies not q. Can someone also tell me what modus ponens means and how it's used in the context?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematics and not directly about programming / coding / software algorithms / programming tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the relevant claims from the image:

1. p (given)
2. p -> r (given)
3. (3-6 snipped)
4. r (modus ponens 1, 2)

The [Wikipedia article on Modus Ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) explains this pretty well. Quoting with some parts removed/changed:

> The argument form has two premises (hypothesis). The first premise is that P, the antecedent of the conditional claim, is true.  The second premise is the "if–then" or conditional claim, namely that P implies R. From these two premises it can be logically concluded that R, the consequent of the conditional claim, must be true as well.
>
> An example of an argument that fits the form modus ponens:
>
> - Today is Tuesday. (P)
> - If today is Tuesday, then John will go to work. (P -> R)
> - Therefore, John will go to work. (R)

Modus ponens is the rule of inferences used to generate new logical statements from valid premises.